# WPF TabItem HeaderTemplate style applying inconsistently

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I am getting some strange behavior when I follow the steps provided by other SO answers to how to style tab item headers.
With

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <buttons:MyButtonControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And a tab control as follows

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Buttons">
        <local:Buttons />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Labels">
        <local:Labels />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

I get a tab control that looks like this

[image: Tab control]

How do I get the style to apply to all tab headers? How do I remove the default tab header style around my datatemplate?

**EDIT**

If I style the Template rather than the header template the content stops showing up but at least the border goes away on the header that works.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <buttons:MyButtonControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image: Tab Control after edit]

Comment: What is `<buttons:MyButtonControl />`?

Comment: It is a custom control that inherits directly from Button.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this question and not comment why?

Comment: I upvoted just to negate the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing part appears to have been a `ContentPresenter` with the `ContentSource` property set to Header.

(Also using a button in the header prevents the tab from being clicked on because the button eats the click event.)

This code displays correctly.

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Border>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header">
                        <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```